# Is arbitrary buffer position at the beginning of a line?

Tags: point, lines

What's the simplest way to check whether a given point value `p` is at the beginning of some line or not? Is there anything simpler than `(save-excursion (goto-char p) (= p (point-at-bol)))` or `(member (char-before p) '(nil \n))`?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the function `bolp`:

> `bolp` is a built-in function in `../editfns.c'.
>
> `(bolp)`
>
> Return `t` if point is at the beginning of a line.
>
> This function does
>   not change global state, including the match data.

Usually you get a buffer position via `(point)`, thus simply issuing `(bolp)` will be enough. If the point has been moved, use `goto-char` in advance.

Comment: This only slightly simpler than `point-at-bol` since you still have to use `save-excursion` if you don't want to move point. `char-before` still seems simplest.